# how to create a histogram by using dataframes in r?

Tags: r

I want to create a histogram, my data is stored in a variable `Z`. Calling `hist(Z)` is showing an error. I tried changing `Z` to numeric but it is still showing errors:

```
Z=as.numeric(Z)
 Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

---

```
year <- c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2013)
disconnected_ppl <- c(116, 54, 310, 110)
df <- data.frame(year=year, disconnected_ppl=disconnected_ppl)
df

year      disconnected_ppl
2010      116
2011       54
2012      310
2013      110
```

I want to create a histogram of year on `xlab` and `disconnected_ppl` on `ylab`. Each bar plot should be mentioned by the years and names on both the axis but I got the graph in this way:

[image]

As am new to `R` can you please suggest me which is the right option to choose histograms or bar plot?

Comment: Are you sure you want a histogram? Or do you mean a barplot?

Comment: It is very difficult to provide help without looking at some data and your code. Please see the link here regarding posting a reproducible example in `R` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try this?

```
year <- c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2013)
disconnected_ppl <- c(116, 54, 310, 110)
df <- data.frame(year=year, disconnected_ppl=disconnected_ppl)
barplot(df$di,df$year, xlab = "Year", ylab = "disconnected_ppl", names=c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2013))
```

Or in ggplot:

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)
qplot(year, data=df, geom="bar", weight=disconnected_ppl, ylab="disconnected_ppl")
```

Comment: @arshia did my answer help?